# How to start at a specific index in a CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My problem is that when I present this CollectionViewController which has 2 cells with a horizontal layout, I'd like to start at index 1 and not index 0.
What am I missing?

```
class Controller: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let cellId = "cell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    scrollToIndex(index: 1)
    setupSwipeView()
}

func setupSwipeView() {
    if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    }
    collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.cellId, for: indexPath)
    return cell
}


func scrollToIndex(index: Int) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
    collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .right, animated: false)
}

}
```

Comment: Did you try scrolling in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`? Do your cells take entire screen?

Comment: Ok putting it into viewDidAppear works. Thanks, I didn't think about that.

Comment: But now the problem is that the second cell isn't showing right away. When the view loads, the first cell appears for like half a second and then it scrolls to index 1.

Comment: There's always `viewWillAppear` to try ;)

Comment: Oh yes that's it. Perfect thanks!

Comment: You should try to set your data source and delegate in the view did load and then right after that use the scroll to index function. How are you setting your data source and delegate now? In the storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

No need to do anything in `viewWillAppear` and `viweDidAppear`, just try this one in your collection view `willDisplay cell` delegate method:

Swift 3 and above:

```
var startWithIndexPath: IndexPath? = .init(item: 1, section: 0)
    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if let startWithIndexPath = startWithIndexPath {
       if collectionView.isValidIndexPath(indexpath: startWithIndexPath) {
           self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: startWithIndexPath, at: .left, animated: false)
       }
       self.startWithIndexPath = nil
   }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure you are providing valid IndexPath which exist in collection view and cell items should be these already and this logic should execute only once.

Comment: No. This code will run for each and every cell to be displayed. Sounds like a cpu waste.

Comment: @Desdenova `willDisplay cell` will call for every cell as like `cellForItemAt indexPath` and it is not a CPU waste until you are not doing major unwanted repetitively calculation in that, there are many more other collection view delegate methods like prefetching delegates which are called for each cell coming on screen. 
My focus on code where we are scrolling collection view on particular index path should execute once.